# Modify RAMPS 1.4 adding external MOSFET for heat bed: can I remove original mosfet?

Tags: power, mosfet

I have a GT2560 board for my 3D printer. It is a custom board based on RAMPS 1.4 + Arduino mixed togheter in only one board.
(here you can find [RAMPS 1.4 schematic](https://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/3/3f/Arduinomegapololushieldschematic.png))

I have some issues with the heat bed connector caused due to the high current, I bought an external MOSFET board like these one:
https://3dprint.wiki/reprap/electronics/heatbed_mosfet

This module has a rectifier just after the 2 pin signal connector, an optocoupler, and a mosftet and connectors for high current. The rectifier has been inserted to avoid polarity issue on the signal connector.

I read the instructions and how to connect it, but I cannot understand why they suggest to connect it to the heatbed 2 pin connector instead of directly on the old mosfet gate signal.

My plan was to desolder the original MOSFET (the STP55N06 in the 'Heaters & Fans' schematic section) solder a cable to the gate pin hole and connect it to the 2pin connector on the external mosfet board.

It is valid alternative? 
If it is a bad idea, can you tell me the reason to use the original mosfet out?

Comment: Looks like they intend the old interface to drive an optocoupler. The gate signal may not be adequate to drive the optocoupler without modifications, but without schematics this cannot be an authoritative answer and must be just a speculative comment.

Comment: It would be unwise to modify your motherboard since you then make it a unique part. If it fails at any time you then need to modify the replacement. This module is designed to interface to the RAMPS board ….why not use it as designed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yep, there's an optocoupler near the transistor, and a rectifier near the signal connector (so you can connect the signal wire to the heatbed connector without taking care of + an - are).

Comment: @JackCreasey I have no problem to use it as designed :) I just asking why they choosed that solution which involve to use 2 mosfet instead of one. As far as I understand, the same result can be obtained desoldering the original STP55N06 from the board and moving it to another PCB piece with dimensioned routes and connectors, right?

Comment: @Noisemaker To design an extender with the broadest applicability you do it as they have done. Asking or expecting customers to modify a board or fitting extra connectors would be more difficult and potentially more costly.